# In going over some old guitar music theory notes of mine, i found this. What does it mean?

Tags: guitar, theory, chords

In going over some old guitar music theory notes of mine, I found this.

```
G  Am   Bm   C  D  Em
```

I appreciate that the chords are those of the major scale in G.

However, over the chords are these numbers

```
3,  0/5,  1/7,  3,  5,  7/0
```

Does anyone known of some significance to these numbers in relation to the chords underneath them?

Comment: If the image you posted is supposed to show numbers above the chord names (G, Am, and so forth), I'm not seeing them.  The only numbers I see are on the dots for the fingerings, which presumably refer to finger numbers.

Comment: Checking my own question, the site seems to have replaced my text with the image. Ill see what I can do about that.

Comment: In the meantime, the numbers are 3,  0/5, 1/7,  3,  5,  7/0

Comment: Pure speculation that seems to fit: each chord can be played in the position(s) reflected by the numbers. G can be played in third position, Am either open or fifth position, etc. Except Bm would normally be played in 2nd position or 7th. Hmmm.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yeah, I'd almost guarantee that's it … the root positions except the B is a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(The comments address this question, but the site still marks this as "unanswered," so I'm adding one.)

The first line shows the diatonic triads in G major. With a scale of `G A B C D E F♯ G`, you can create:

- `G B D`, which is G major
- `A C E`, Am
- `B D F♯`, Bm
- `C E G`, CM
- `D F♯ A`, DM
- `E G B`, Em

The only one missing is `F♯ A C`, which is F♯ diminished. Perhaps your theory teacher was only teaching the *consonant* triads (that is, major and minor). Diminished (along with augmented) are *dissonant* triads.

As for the numbers, these seem to be the guitar positions in which you can play these triads. G is played in 3rd position, Am is either in open or fifth position, and so on.

The only flaw here is the position for Bm: instead of 1st and 7th position, Bm is played in *2nd* or 7th position.

Thus your notes should read:

```
    G    Am    Bm    C    D    Em
    3,   0/5,  2/7,  3,   5,   7/0
```